# jQuery UI datepicker date range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to setup two date pickers like this http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range. But if you manually type in a date into that example you can break the code. e.g. select a from date, then the picker stops you from selecting a date before the from date, but you can manually type in a to date that is earlier.

I have set up the example here http://jsfiddle.net/Ruhley/s3h5L/

Comment: It's not obvious to me what you're asking for.

Comment: two jquery date pickers like in the demo. But the rule that the from date has to be before the to date can be broken if you manually type in a date. i can't figure out how to fix this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. first idea

   - use the `beforeShow` instead of `onSelect` to set the max/min date range. You still can enter manually wrong values, but as soon as you try to open a datepicker it will auto correct itself.
   - to avoid manual tampering, you can make `readonly` the fields.
2. second idea

   - use the `beforeShow` and at the same time do some manual checking at the `change` event of the fields. ( http://jsfiddle.net/s3h5L/4/ )

Answer (score 1):

**this works ok for me but cannot change from date after click once . (by mistake) . i guess in from date picker all dates can be selectable instead of future dates**

```
<script>    
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#datepicker1, #datepicker2" ).datepicker({
        changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",


        beforeShow: function( ) {
            var other = this.id == "from" ? "#datepicker2" : "#datepicker1";
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "maxDate" : "minDate";
            var selectedDate = $(other).datepicker('getDate');

            $(this).datepicker( "option", option, selectedDate );
        }
    }).change(function(){
        var other = this.id == "from" ? "#datepicker2" : "#datepicker1";

        if ( $('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate') > $('#datepicker2').datepicker('getDate') )
            $(other).datepicker('setDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate') );
    });
});
</script>
```