# date range picker default value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datepicker

Hi all I'm using daterangepicker.jQuery.js

( http://trac.vtiger.com/cgi-bin/trac.cgi/browser/vtigercrm/branches/6.0.0/vtiger6/libraries/jquery/jquery-ui/third-party/jQuery-UI-Date-Range-Picker/js/daterangepicker.jQuery.js?rev=13838 )

per default it's initialized at 1970-01-01 and i've searched in the whole javascript but i didn't find it does someone know how to change this value ? and if possible how to limit the calendar in today's date please

( EDIT )

I've tried

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                    $('#rangeBa, #rangeBb').daterangepicker();
             });
             $(document).ready(function(){
                var date = '17-05-2013';
                $('#rangeBa, #rangeBb').daterangepicker('setDate', date);?
            })
        </script>
```

but it's not working

Comment: 1970-01-01 is the [start of time for Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: give a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466896/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-range

Answer (score 5):

This works like a charm. You can try it.

```
var today = new Date();
var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1);
$('#rangeBa, #rangeBb').daterangepicker({ 
    startDate: today, // after open picker you'll see this dates as picked
    endDate: endDate,
    locale: {
       format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    }
}, function (start, end, label) {
    //what to do after change
}).val(today + " - " + endDate); //set it to see it inside input (don't forget to format dates)
```

If you want to limit date range just use minDate and maxDate options.

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var date = '17-05-2013';
    $("#my_input").datepicker('setDate', date);​
})
```

Make sure that the datepicker date format would be like 'dd-mm-yyyy' only
As per your edit

```
/*$(function(){
            $('#rangeBa, #rangeBb').daterangepicker();    
         });*/
         $(document).ready(function(){
            var date = '17-05-2013';
            $('#rangeBa, #rangeBb').daterangepicker();
            $('#rangeBa, #rangeBb').daterangepicker('setDate', date);
        })
```

and you can try by date object like

```
defaultDate = new Date(2013,05,17);
$('#rangeBa, #rangeBb').daterangepicker('setDate', defaultDate);
```

Comment: do i have to put this in the javascript file or in my php page ?

Comment: @Gautam3164 the problem is that when i add your function i don't have the datepicker when i click on the field anymore : /

Comment: I already told you that date format....check it once and change its value as per the date format of yours

Comment: now with your new function i can see it but the date is still the same though the date format is the same

Answer (score 2):

try it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var today = new Date();
        $(function () {
        $('#rangeBa, #rangeBb').daterangepicker({ 
        "startDate": today,
        },
        locale: {
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
        },
                function (start) {
                    startdate = start.format('DD-MM-YYYY')
                });
        });
</script>
```

You can try like this and daterangepicker take default date of today..

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2018 - 01/15/2018" />
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        opens: 'left'
      }, function(start, end, label) {
        console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      });
    });
    </script>
```